# Returning a promise in an async function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

It's my understanding that these two functions will have the same behavior in JavaScript:

```
const whatever1 = (): Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(4);
    });
};

const whatever2 = async (): Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(4);
    });
};
```

But TypeScript seems to not like the second one, it says:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Is this a bug in TypeScript, or am I misunderstanding something about async functions?

Comment: note that using `async` in your second function is kind of useless, because the function will return a Promise in no time and won't clog the execution whatsoever.

Comment: offtopic, but if you don't really care about promise return you can use `Promise<any>`

Comment: I know this is old, but if you know the value being returned is a number, you can do this `resolve(4 as number);`

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It's complicated.

First of all, in this code

```
const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(4);
});
```

the type of `p` is inferred as `Promise<{}>`. There is [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5254) about this on typescript github, so arguably this is a bug, because obviously (for a human), `p` should be `Promise<number>`.

Then, `Promise<{}>` is compatible with `Promise<number>`, because basically the only property a promise has is `then` method, and `then` is compatible in these two promise types in accordance with [typescript rules for function types compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance). That's why there is no error in `whatever1`.

But the purpose of `async` is to pretend that you are dealing with actual values, not promises, and then you get the error in `whatever2` because `{}` is obvioulsy not compatible with `number`.

So the `async` behavior is the same, but currently some workaround is necessary to make typescript compile it. You could simply provide explicit generic argument when creating a promise like this:

```
const whatever2 = async (): Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
        resolve(4);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 40):

When you do `new Promise((resolve)...` the type inferred was `Promise<{}>` because you should have used `new Promise<number>((resolve)`.

It is interesting that this issue was only highlighted when the `async` keyword was added. I would recommend reporting this issue to the TS team [on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues).

There are many ways you can get around this issue. All the following functions have the same behavior:

```
const whatever1 = () => {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
        resolve(4);
    });
};

const whatever2 = async () => {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
        resolve(4);
    });
};

const whatever3 = async () => {
    return await new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
        resolve(4);
    });
};

const whatever4 = async () => {
    return Promise.resolve(4);
};

const whatever5 = async () => {
    return await Promise.resolve(4);
};

const whatever6 = async () => Promise.resolve(4);

const whatever7 = async () => await Promise.resolve(4);
```

In your IDE you will be able to see that the inferred type for all these functions is `() => Promise<number>`.

Comment: If there was a reject somewhere in the Promise function how would the return type still be the same?